# Having a 2.4/5 Ghz wireless router next to us is healthy?

Tags: radiation, bioelectromagnetics

What is the **official** distance that we need to keep from a 20 dBm wireless router that has 2x2 MiMo 3 dBi antennas?

The given router is this: 
https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-lite/

Ex.: can we be 1 m far to this wireless router, 24h a day (most of the time) for the rest of our life? Or can it cause ANY reproduction/cancer issues?

So far I googled for several hours.. but still cannot decide that is it a good idea or not, to put the wireless router 1 m far for 24h a day.

Comment: Consider that you have been bombarded by much more powerful radio signals 24/7 since the day you were conceived. Among the sources: radio, television, radar, mobile phones, and interstellar sources. Many of those sources are orders of magnitude more powerful than a wifi router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/engineering-technology/electromagnetic-compatibility-division/radio-frequency-safety/faq/rf-safety#Q9) depending on the frequency, a few Watts per kg absorbed RF radiation is an appropriate safety limit. Since 20 dBm corresponds to a total emitted power of 0.1 Watt, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: hopefully this is the good answer :)